# Reverse SHA-256 sigma0 function within complexity of O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, hash, cryptography, reverse-engineering

### Introduction

As a part of SHA-256 hashing algorithm, there's a function that is often being referred as `σ1`, or `sigma0` for convenience. Basically, it takes X as input, where X is 32-bit unsigned value. Then converts it like this:

```
ROTATE_RIGHT(X, 7) ^ ROTATE_RIGHT(X, 18) ^ SHIFT_RIGHT(X, 3)
```

A bit of explanation, if you need one:

- ROTATE_RIGHT(X, Y) - rotates X's bits to the right by Y
- SHIFT_RIGHT(X, Y) - shifts X's bits to the right by Y, so the first Y bits of the result are always 0

Also, if you need the code, here's the full version in Python:

```python
def rotate_right(x, y):
    return (((x & 0xffffffff) >> (y & 31)) | (x << (32 - (y & 31)))) & 0xffffffff

def shift_right(x, n):
    return (x & 0xffffffff) >> n

def sigma0(x):
    return rotate_right(x, 7) ^ rotate_right(x, 18) ^ shift_right(x, 3)
```

### Reverse function

I started wondering if that thing is reversible, and, to my surprise, it didn't take long to write a function which, by given `sigma0`'s output, returns input of that function, or, simply put, reverses `sigma0` function. I won't put the code here, because it was written in Node.js and modified a lot by more complex needs of searching particular `sigma0` inputs by masks, but I'd like to give you a basic idea of how I solved it, so maybe you could enlighten me with some fresh ideas on how to achieve what I need.

My solution is simple, but it is also recursive. We know that every output's bit is the result of XOR operation of two or three input's bits. So I made a dependence table so that I can see how are output's bits are being affected by input ones:

```
I:  00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31

R7  25,26,27,28,29,30,31,00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24
R18 14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13
S3  zz,zz,zz,00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
O:  00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
```

What is this thing about? Say, in the output's 1st bit we have 1. For convenience, I'll write it as `O[0]`, `O[1]`, ... `O[31]`, so `O[x]` is (x+1)th bit of the output. The same for input, marked as `I`.

So, `O[0] == 1`. In the table above we see that `O[0]` is the result of XOR operation of `I[25]` and `I[14]`. Which implies that one and only one of those input's bits must be 1. So at this point we could say that we can create two suitable masks for the input:

```
##############0#########1#######
##############1#########0#######
```

Those masks are key to the solution, at least, to mine. `#` means any value (0 or 1). When we create masks, we call the recursive function for the next bit, but preserving the mask. If we are out of possible masks that would suit previous mask, the previous mask has no solution, and if we reach 32nd bit, we're guaranteed to have no sharps in the masks, and this will be the answer.

First, I need to tell you that this thing works. But on Node.js it calculates every value for about 100ms and I have no idea what is the worst complexity of my recursion algorithm, because it's quite hard to measure. It doesn't satisfy me, and I broke my brains trying to solve this O(n).

### Problem

I'm wondering if it's possible to write a function that reverses `sigma0` within complexity of O(n), where `n` is amount of bits in the input/output and it equals to 32, without recursion, masks or trees, simply and fast.

I haven't concluded any mathematical proof for my statement, but I tested lots of different values and I can confidently claim that the amount of input values is equal to the amount of output values of this function, and both are equal to `2^32 - 1`. In other words, for every output, there is one and only one possible input of `sigma0` function.

Which gives me a thought that the fact `sigma0` original function produces result with complexity of O(n) implies that the reverse function must have a solution that also works O(n).

If you mathematically prove me that this is impossible, I'd also accept this answer, but I haven't found anything that would indicate the impossibility of this task.

### Resource-devouring workaround

In case I had free 16gb of ram, I'd be able to pre-calculate all the possible values into the file, and then load it into ram as a huge array. But it's not a solution since there are other 3 similar functions, and to do that for all of them I'd need 64gb of ram which is too expensive and excessive for this simple task.

### UPD: Gaussian Elimination

Thanks to Artjom B.'s comment, I found a great way to solve XOR equations via Gaussian Elimination. Currently I'm trying to solve a matrix like this:

```
Input:  00000000100110101000111011101001
Output: 01110001101010000010010011100110

0:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
1:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
2:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 | 1
3:  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 | 1
4:  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 | 0
5:  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 | 0
6:  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 | 0
7:  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
8:  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
9:  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
10: 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
11: 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
12: 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
13: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 | 0
14: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 | 0
15: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 | 0
16: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 | 0
17: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 | 0
18: 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
19: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
20: 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
21: 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
22: 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
23: 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
24: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
25: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
26: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
27: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
28: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0
29: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 | 1
30: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 | 1
31: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 | 0
```

Published the matrix so you could see how it looks and not waste your time on creating it by yourself. I'll update my question once I solved it or not.

Comment: "Which gives me a thought that the fact sigma0 original function produces result with complexity of O(n) implies that the reverse function must have a solution that also works O(n)." This is not true at all. There are many functions that are simple in one direction, but their inverse is not. This is the foundation of most modern cryptography. You're stating a much more aggressive version of P = NP as though it were a given rather than one of the great questions of complexity theory. The whole point of cryptographic hashes that there is no known efficient inverse.

Comment: In any case, this question is off topic for Stack Overflow since it's not related to a particular implementation. It could be relevant on crypto.stackexchange.com, but if you believe you've devised an efficient reversal of SHA-256, assume you haven't. Looking over your work, it seems you've proven that you can find a preimage to a hash given arbitrary time or arbitrary memory (this is a well-known fact, and is trivially proven for any hash function).

Comment: I haven't devised an efficient reversal of sha256, it was academic with a bit of sporting interest in doing so. I hardly imagine that even finding a solution to my problem would help you reverse the whole sha256, and I never mentioned this in my question as the primary purpose. The intention of my whole research is to find out what makes sha256 so irreversible, so you've mistakenly taken me for the sha256 reverse inventor :)

Comment: But I didn't see anything in my question that would indicate it as off-topic. I'd be glad if you elaborate.

Comment: You seem to have discovered what makes it so irreversible. It's very difficult to reverse the individual stages. There's no current proof that it's impossible to reverse the stages. Everyone would love to find such a proof. No one knows how to reverse it, and it's widely believed that it's irreversible, however. (As to why it's off-topic, StackOverflow relates to programming problems. What you're describing is not tied to any particular aspect of programming. It's a general question of cryptography.) See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: By "reverse" I mean "in polynomial time." As you've discovered with your recursive algorithm, the problem isn't doing it; it's doing it in time that grows reasonably in proportion to the number of bits in the hash. Given unbounded time, it is *always* possible to find a preimage to a hash.

Comment: Have you actually tried to use Gaussian Elimination over GF(2)? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169921/how-to-solve-system-of-linear-equations-of-xor-operation

Comment: No, never heard of this method before. I'll try and, if succeed, write an answer to my own question.

Comment: @RobNapier This particular sub-operation is quite efficiently reversible, see my answer.

Comment: @orlp Thanks for the answer. While IMO the question wasn't originally well suited to Stack Overflow, I think the answer in the form of a detailed and powerful implementation more than brings it on topic (and suggests the question may be fine as well). Retracted close vote.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If we view `sigma0` as a function over a GF(2)<sup>32</sup> vector, you will note that it's linear. Addition in GF(2)<sup>32</sup> is just the binary XOR:

```python
>>> sigma0(235 ^ 352124)
2045075788

>>> sigma0(235) ^ sigma0(352124)
2045075788
```

This means that if we can find `sigma0(x0) = 0b1`, `sigma0(x1) = 0b10`, etc we can easily invert anything bit-by-bit.  We can easily find these inverses with `z3`:

```python
import z3

def z3_sigma0(x):
    return z3.RotateRight(x, 7) ^ z3.RotateRight(x, 18) ^ z3.LShR(x, 3)

s = z3.Solver()
xs = [z3.BitVec(f"x{i}", 32) for i in range(32)]
for i in range(32):
    s.add(z3_sigma0(xs[i]) == (1 << i))
print(s.check())
m = s.model()
for i in range(32):
    print("x{:02} = 0x{:08x}".format(i, m[xs[i]].as_long()))
```

This instantly outputs:

```python
sat
x00 = 0x185744e9
x01 = 0x30ae89d2
x02 = 0x615d13a4
x03 = 0xdaed63a1
x04 = 0x9cd03a8e
x05 = 0x08fdcc39
x06 = 0x11fb9872
x07 = 0x23f730e4
x08 = 0x5fb92521
x09 = 0xbf724a42
x10 = 0x57ee6948
x11 = 0xafdcd290
x12 = 0x76b358ec
x13 = 0xf531f531
x14 = 0xc36917ae
x15 = 0xb78f9679
x16 = 0x4615d13e
x17 = 0x947ce695
x18 = 0x19a4740f
x19 = 0x2b1facf7
x20 = 0x4e681d07
x21 = 0x84877ee7
x22 = 0x385344eb
x23 = 0x70a689d6
x24 = 0xf91a5745
x25 = 0xc36917af
x26 = 0xb78f967b
x27 = 0x4615d13a
x28 = 0x8c2ba274
x29 = 0x290afdcd
x30 = 0x4a42bf73
x31 = 0x94857ee6
```

Thus we can use this to make our inversion function:

```python
sigma0_singleton_inverses = [
    0x185744e9, 0x30ae89d2, 0x615d13a4, 0xdaed63a1, 0x9cd03a8e, 0x08fdcc39,
    0x11fb9872, 0x23f730e4, 0x5fb92521, 0xbf724a42, 0x57ee6948, 0xafdcd290,
    0x76b358ec, 0xf531f531, 0xc36917ae, 0xb78f9679, 0x4615d13e, 0x947ce695,
    0x19a4740f, 0x2b1facf7, 0x4e681d07, 0x84877ee7, 0x385344eb, 0x70a689d6,
    0xf91a5745, 0xc36917af, 0xb78f967b, 0x4615d13a, 0x8c2ba274, 0x290afdcd,
    0x4a42bf73, 0x94857ee6
]

def inv_sigma0(x):
    r = 0
    for i in range(32):
        if x & (1 << i):
            r ^= sigma0_singleton_inverses[i]
    return r
```

And indeed:

```python
>>> def test_inv_once():
...     r = random.randrange(2**32)
...     return inv_sigma0(sigma0(r)) == r
>>> all(test_inv_once() for _ in range(10**6))
True
```

---

The above can be written completely loopless and branchless:

```py
def inv_sigma0(x):
    xn = ~x
    r  = (((xn >>  0) & 1) - 1) & 0x185744e9
    r ^= (((xn >>  1) & 1) - 1) & 0x30ae89d2
    r ^= (((xn >>  2) & 1) - 1) & 0x615d13a4
    r ^= (((xn >>  3) & 1) - 1) & 0xdaed63a1
    r ^= (((xn >>  4) & 1) - 1) & 0x9cd03a8e
    r ^= (((xn >>  5) & 1) - 1) & 0x08fdcc39
    r ^= (((xn >>  6) & 1) - 1) & 0x11fb9872
    r ^= (((xn >>  7) & 1) - 1) & 0x23f730e4
    r ^= (((xn >>  8) & 1) - 1) & 0x5fb92521
    r ^= (((xn >>  9) & 1) - 1) & 0xbf724a42
    r ^= (((xn >> 10) & 1) - 1) & 0x57ee6948
    r ^= (((xn >> 11) & 1) - 1) & 0xafdcd290
    r ^= (((xn >> 12) & 1) - 1) & 0x76b358ec
    r ^= (((xn >> 13) & 1) - 1) & 0xf531f531
    r ^= (((xn >> 14) & 1) - 1) & 0xc36917ae
    r ^= (((xn >> 15) & 1) - 1) & 0xb78f9679
    r ^= (((xn >> 16) & 1) - 1) & 0x4615d13e
    r ^= (((xn >> 17) & 1) - 1) & 0x947ce695
    r ^= (((xn >> 18) & 1) - 1) & 0x19a4740f
    r ^= (((xn >> 19) & 1) - 1) & 0x2b1facf7
    r ^= (((xn >> 20) & 1) - 1) & 0x4e681d07
    r ^= (((xn >> 21) & 1) - 1) & 0x84877ee7
    r ^= (((xn >> 22) & 1) - 1) & 0x385344eb
    r ^= (((xn >> 23) & 1) - 1) & 0x70a689d6
    r ^= (((xn >> 24) & 1) - 1) & 0xf91a5745
    r ^= (((xn >> 25) & 1) - 1) & 0xc36917af
    r ^= (((xn >> 26) & 1) - 1) & 0xb78f967b
    r ^= (((xn >> 27) & 1) - 1) & 0x4615d13a
    r ^= (((xn >> 28) & 1) - 1) & 0x8c2ba274
    r ^= (((xn >> 29) & 1) - 1) & 0x290afdcd
    r ^= (((xn >> 30) & 1) - 1) & 0x4a42bf73
    r ^= (((xn >> 31) & 1) - 1) & 0x94857ee6
    return r
```

The fastest version probably probably is this one, grouping by 16 bits at a time using a 2 × 2<sup>16</sup> size lookup table (or similarly four lookups into a 4 × 2<sup>8</sup> sized table).

```python
sigma0_16bit_inverse_lo = [inv_sigma0(x)       for x in range(2**16)]
sigma0_16bit_inverse_hi = [inv_sigma0(x << 16) for x in range(2**16)]
def fast_inv_sigma0(x):
    return (sigma0_16bit_inverse_lo[x & 0xffff] ^
            sigma0_16bit_inverse_hi[(x >> 16) & 0xffff])
```

Comment: It is incredible. And I'm gonna tell you how incredible your answer is. First, I never knew that s0(x ^ y) = s0(x) ^ s0(y), now I know thanks to you. Second, I've been searching all over the internet something like z3 library, and never suspect the existence of such an immense and powerful tool. Third, you answered my question with 100% viable solution, detailing each step, and it deserves separate gratitude, because I never heard of GF(2) before yesterday. You deserve more than 1 upvote.

Comment: @MaxSeid Don't forget to check out my updated answer with the extra-fast version at the bottom that's just 1 XOR and two lookups into ~500KiB worth of lookup tables.

Comment: @MaxSeid And yes, `z3` is an immensely powerful tool, magic at times, but it can very quickly go from 'solve my problem with z3' to 'z3 is useless for my problem', and sometimes you don't know which it is before simply trying out the solver. If you had use Gaussian elimination on your matrix and read them out as binary integers row-by-row, you would've found the same integers I found using `z3`.

Comment: Yes, I know that if I solved it with Gaussian elimination, I'd come up with those integers. The problem is that I never heard of this method before, and I tried to solve that matrix above manually with no success, just it was shown in the answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169921/how-to-solve-system-of-linear-equations-of-xor-operation). I just believe there must be some particular methodology on solving elimination matrices, but I searched and everything referred to Galois fields, which is complicated and massive topic that I haven't managed to learn within one day so far.

Comment: @MaxSeid Gaussian elimination is a very basic and simple algorithm, you can try looking in the wiki or some step-by-step walkthroughs on youtube. The only difference when you do Gaussian elimination over GF(2) is that instead of doing addition you do XOR, and you don't have to ever divide (because you can only divide by 1 - a no-op).

Comment: @orlp You said, "Addition in GF(2)32 is just the binary XOR" so shouldn't sigma0(x + y) = sigma0(x) + sigma0(y) hold ( I checked it doesn't ) like the XOR version you mentioned in your answer? or Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @GauthamJ `sigma0(a ^ b) = sigma0(a) ^ sigma0(b)` holds. It's linear when we use XOR as our addition (like in GF(2^32)).